# Get numpy ndarray offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Question: How do I calculate the "offset" from a view of ndarray?

Example 1

Input:

```
a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
b = a[1:]
# some procedure to get offset
print(offset)
```

Expected Output

```
1
```

because, `uint8` is 1 byte object.

Example 2

Input:

```
a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.ndarray((9,), a.dtype, a.data, offset=1)
# some procedure to get offset
print(offset)
```

Expected output:

```
1
```

This is (maybe) exactly the same procedure shown in Example 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [485]: a = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
     ...: b = a[1:]
```

Compare these:

```
In [486]: a.__array_interface__['data'][0]
Out[486]: 38965232
In [487]: b.__array_interface__['data'][0]
Out[487]: 38965233
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply! This was exactly what I wanted!